# How do I view version history on my Foundry Slate App

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

For `Foundry Slate`, I've made an edit that I want to revert as it had broken my usecase. I've tried looking at the documentation and was unable to find it, but I know a commit history between users is kept somewhere in the UI. Wanted to know where in the UI I could find it?

```
Snippet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit view, you can click the Actions dropdown in the top-right area of the screen and select Compare versions to be able to revert.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the version history of your Slate document in the top right corner under
Actions -> Settings -> Versions

It should be noted that this includes the commit history of not only yourself but everyone who had contributed to the Slate app. The difference between commits is calculated by the produced JSON when the Slate app is compiled down.

Thanks